# Explanation of "a" in "a-basking"

Tags: grammar

It is the first time I have encountered such a use of "a" combined with an -ing form.*Maybe you will be a-basking in the sun this afternoon.* Is there any reasonable explanation?

Comment: For more examples, see [the Twelve days of Christmas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song))

Comment: There are different  hystorical explanatios , but non of them is definitive.

Answer (score -2):

It is a southern reference, without reason. You might go a-huntin' for rabbits, or be a-baskin' in the sun. I spend time correcting my southern influenced grammar and vocabulary, I will have to watch out for this one.

Comment: -1 for "without reason".   Josh61's comment, above,  included a link to a reasonable explanation before you posted this answer.

Comment: Lama, do you think it is used only in southern American dialects.